# How can I change my cursor to a .cur file cursor?

Tags: cursor

I have downloaded a cursor of the .cur file type and I want to use it on the latest version of Ubuntu. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26187085/3644902

Answer (score 0):

Install `imagemagick` -> `sudo apt-get install imagemagick` and convert the cursor to a `.png` file:

```
convert icon:file.cur file.png
```

Then use xcursorgen:

```
  xcursorgen [config-file] [output-file]
```

So you'll need to convert each png individually.